# Convert rows into a single extended column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Hi I would like to take a row1 of data and put it into a column, then do the same with row2 and extend the column.

Ex:

**This**

```
 1   2   3   4   5
 6   7   8   9  10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21
```

**to this**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
...
```

how could I do that in bash?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the sequences of spaces with newlines would seem simplest.

`tr`can do that (`-s` is key here):

```
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' < file.txt
```

Though that leaves an empty first line since there's a space before the `1`.

or with GNU sed:

```
sed -E -e 's/^ +//; s/ +$//; s/ +/\n/g' < file.txt
```

The first two substitutions remove leading and trailing spaces from each line to prevent spurious empty lines.

(You need GNU sed for the `\n` to work.)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep`, you can use:

```
grep -Eo '\S+'
```

Which prints all the sequences of one or more (`+`) non-whitespace characters (`\S`) one per line.

Answer (score 2):

Another couple of options:

1. using `awk`, with output field separator set to newline

   ```
   awk '{NF+=0} 1' OFS='\n' file
   ```
2. using the `rs` (**r**e**s**hape) utility, setting the number of output columns to `1` (and `0` for the rows to indicate "as many as requird")

   ```
   rs 0 1 < file
   ```